# ¿Con Pandas.groupby puedo resolver este problema?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Este es un DF que contiene los registros historicos de partidos de la liga Inglesa y la pregunta es como puedo obtener los campeones por temporada.

|  | Season | Team | Wins | Losses | Draws | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1993 | Arsenal | 15 | 16 | 11 | 56 |
| 1 | 1993 | Aston Villa | 21 | 10 | 11 | 74 |
| 2 | 1993 | Blackburn | 20 | 11 | 11 | 71 |
| 3 | 1993 | Chelsea | 14 | 14 | 14 | 56 |
| 4 | 1993 | Coventry City | 13 | 16 | 13 | 52 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 601 | 2022 | Southampton | 9 | 16 | 13 | 40 |
| 602 | 2022 | Tottenham | 22 | 11 | 5 | 71 |
| 603 | 2022 | Watford | 6 | 27 | 5 | 23 |
| 604 | 2022 | West Ham | 16 | 14 | 8 | 56 |
| 605 | 2022 | Wolves | 15 | 17 | 6 | 51 |

---

Esta fue la consulta con la que más me acerqué

```py
df.groupby(['Season'])['Points'].max()
```

y el resultado es

```
Season
1993     84
1994     92
1995     89
1996     82
1997     75
1998     78
1999     79
2000     91
2001     80
2002     87
2003     83
2004     90
2005     95
2006     91
2007     89
2008     87
2009     90
2010     86
2011     80
2012     89
2013     89
2014     86
2015     87
2016     81
2017     93
2018    100
2019     98
2020     99
2021     86
2022     93
```

Efectivamente me entrega el registro máximo por temporada, la función groupby lo hizo correctamente, pero mi duda es como obtengo además el registro del equipo que consiguió dicho puntaje

Answer (score 0):

Tan sencillo como agregar el nombre de la columna a `df.groupby` asi:

```
df.groupby(['Season','Team'])['Points'].max()
```

### Para consultar mas:

[pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)